# How do I save the new Logging configuration on Laravel?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5.7

I want to configure Logging for Slack on Laravel 5.7, I modified the relevant files to do so but the logs keep being stored in the 'daily' logs (which is the default).

Relevant code:

logging.php

```
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'stack'),
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['slack'],
    ],
    'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Logs',
            'level' => 'debug',
    ],
```

.env

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=https://hooks.slack.com/services/...(omitted)
```

Then I want to use it like so:

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
Log::info('Hello World!');
return view('home');
})
```

I think I'm missing something fundamental about modifying config files but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Have you run `php artisan config:clear` (or `php artisan config:cache`) to clear the cached config (or cache it)? (If you run `php artisan config:cache` you can checkout the cached config file in `/bootstrap/cache/config.php`)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when using the slack log.after you make some modifications make sure you run `php artisan config:cache`(to be on a much safer side do `php artisan config:clear`) so the application will be notify that you have make some changes to the logging.php file

Answer (score 0):

Should your .env file not be this

```
LOG_CHANNEL=slack
```

instead of

```
LOG_CHANNEL=stack
```

Comment: It doesn't really matter because i call the sLack channel in the sTack one, like so 
    'channels' => ['slack']

Anyway I tried that and has the same problem

Comment: for me i had to use stack which is the defailt and it worked well